# How to use given function to deliver many strings

Tags: python

I have my function randStr which spits out a random string with N character.

```
def randStr(chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, N=4):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(N))
```

How do I make it so that it returns 1000 of these random and unique small strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: added uniqueness check)

You could use a `while-loop` to iterate until you get 1000 unique words. Note that input string has to be at least 8 char long. To check using [Permutations Calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php), 7P4=840, and 8P4=1680, and 9P4 onwards is greater than that.

```
import string
import random

def randStr(chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, N=4):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(N))

unique_words = []
while len(unique_words) < 1000:
    result = randStr('abcdefgh')
    if result not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(result)
        print(result, end=', ')
print(len(unique_words))
```

Output:

```
cfae, gbca, fgfe, bdhg, decd, gcha, ddgc, babd, bggb, eghe, eeca, ebch, fbec, bgbe, gbbc, dgda, efec, hccd, bgfh, gdbf, ecac, edhd, cfdg, eacf, dgaa, heeb, 
...
egbb, cbed, eefg, gdec, dgcg, cgag, fadc, effe, dahg, fhdb, 1000
```

Comment: oh yea, i missed reading that part, so I've edited my code.

Comment: Checking for existence in a list is very expensive (`O(n)`) while checking in a set is `O(1)`

Comment: oh yea, `set(unique_words)` is a good alternative to skip the check! I'm learning new things, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as that of @black-raven but with more efficient uniqueness check
Note the use of set structure for guaranteed unique strings.

```
import string
import random

def randStr(chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, N=4):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(N))

strings = set()
while len(strings) != 1000:
    newString = randStr('asdf')
    strings.add(newString)
strings = list(strings)
```

Comment: `strings = set()` seems a good approach.. I'm learning new things, thanks!